# C++ char*[] to char** conversion

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have this simple code that compiles without errors/warnings:

```
void f(int&, char**&){}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    f(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

And next similar code that doesn't compile:

```
void f(int&, char**&){}

int main()
{
    int argc = 2;
    char* argv[] = { "", "", nullptr };
    f(argc, argv); 
    //@VS2013 error: cannot convert argument 2 from 'char *[3]' to 'char **&'
    //@GCC error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'char**&' from an rvalue of type 'char**'
    return 0;
}
```

Why `char*[]` can be converted to `char**&` in the first sample and can't be converted in the second sample? Does it matter if the size is known at compile time?

EDIT: I think there are 2 conversions needed in the second case, and only one implicit conversion can be done by compiler.

This code compiles fine:

```
void f(int&, char**&){}

int main()
{
    int argc = 2;
    char* temp[] = { "", "", nullptr };
    char** argv = temp;
    f(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that you have more problems than that (related to C++11 compatibility), [see live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b27bbe925d88d735).

Comment: In function parameter, `char* name[]` and `char** name` are *equivalent* - they designate the same thing (more specifically, the former is transformed into the latter).

Comment: @rubenvb I know const char* to char* is deprecated in C++11. Also other const correctness problems are present here...

Comment: `void f(int&, char*[]){}`

Comment: @Felics is was deprecated in C++03. It is forbidden in C++11.

Comment: @Jefffrey There's no rvalue reference in his code.  C++11 doesn't make any significant changes to his problem (except maybe to forbid his initializations with `""`, instead of just deprecating them).

Comment: The standard defines the array to pointer conversion (at 4.2.1) as producing a prvalue (which cannot be passed as an lvalue reference to a function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jefffrey's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467514/c-char-to-char-conversion#comment30585757_20467514) references the standard, here it is:

> 4.2 Array-to-pointer conversion [conv.array]
>
> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted
> to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The result is a pointer to the
> ﬁrst element of the array.

And a prvalue is:

> A prvalue ("pure" rvalue) is an expression that identifies a temporary
> object (or a subobject thereof) or is a value not associated with any
> object.

You cannot bind a non-const reference to a temporary.

```
int& i = int(); // error

char* argv[] = { "", "", nullptr };
// the result of the conversion is a prvalue
char**& test = argv; // error
```

Therefore the following code will happily compile:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int& argc, char** const& argv){
    std::cout << argv[0] << std::endl; // a
}

int main()
{
    int argc = 2;
    char* argv[] = { "a", "b", nullptr };
    f(argc, argv); 
    return 0;
}
```

---

One important thing I glazed over is pointed out in [Kanze's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467514/c-char-to-char-conversion/20469655?noredirect=1#comment30596711_20469655).

In the first example provided in the OP, `char* argv[]` and `char** argv` are equivalent. Therefore, there is no conversion.

```
std::cout << std::is_array<decltype(argv)>::value << std::endl; // false
std::cout << std::is_array<char**>::value << std::endl; // false
std::cout << std::is_array<char*[]>::value << std::endl; // true
std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(argv), char**>::value << std::endl; // true
std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(argv), char*[]>::value << std::endl; // false
```

Comment: if the main() has argv as prarmeter, then isnt that converted to pointer, when we pass it to f()?

Comment: This fails to mention the rewrite of function parameters, which is an important part of understanding what is going on.

Comment: @James The standard says that a conversion occurs. Is it different from how function parameters are treated?

Comment: @remyabel Function parameters declared as arrays are rewritten
to be pointers.  This is why, for example, the OPs first example
compiled.  (A conversion results in an rvalue, and couldn't bind
to a non-const reference.  Because of the rewrite, however,
there is no conversion.)  See §8.3.5/5: "After determining the
type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” or
“function returning T” is adjusted to be “pointer to T” or
“pointer to function returning T,” respectively."

Answer (score 9):

Because despite appearances, the second argument to `main` has
type `char**`.  When used as the declaration of a function
argument, a top level array is rewritten to a pointer, so `char
*[]` is, in fact, `char**`.  This only applies to function
parameters, however.

A `char*[]` (as in your second case) can convert to a `char**`,
but the results of the conversion (as with any conversion) is an
rvalue, and cannot be used to initialize a non-const reference.
Why do you want the reference?  If it is to modify the pointer,
modifying the `char**` argument to `main` is undefined behavior
(formally, in C, at least—I've not checked if C++ is more
liberal here).  And of course, there's no way you can possibly
modify the constant address of an array.  And if you don't want
to modify it, why use a reference?

Comment: I Accepted remy's answer for the standard citation. Thank you! +1

Answer (score 0):

The type of `temp` in

> `char* temp[] = { "", "", nullptr };`

is **not** char*[], it's

> `char*[3]`

The latter can't be implicitly converted to `char**'.

In `main`, the type of `argv` is an unbound `char*` array which is equivalent to `char**`

I admit, it's confusing :)