# String Printer problems: no known conversion for argument X from ‘char (*)[xx]’ to ‘char**’

Tags: c++, string, char, pass-by-reference

If there is one thing I hate about C++ is pointers. Now I checked other thread and could still not make it work. The code is pretty simple, I am passing a string of character in parameter, but I want to pass it in reference to modify the content of the string. I don't want to use STD classes. Here is the code:

The function is declared like this:

```
public: static void bitfield_to_strfield ( s_EnhancedSQLobject_strfield hash[], char **str, int bitfield );
```

I am trying to call the function like this:

```
EnhancedSQLobject::bitfield_to_strfield ( STRFLD_ELEMENTAL_PROPERTY, &p_resistance_str, p_resistance );
```

The string is declared as:

```
private: char p_resistance_str [ EnhancedSQLobject_STRFIELD_LEN ];
```

I get the following error

```
no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘char (*)[94]’ to ‘char**’
```

According to this thread

[C++ char*[] to char** conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467514/c-char-to-char-conversion)

There seems to be some sort of implicit conversion problem. I tried creating a temporary variable before passing it in parameter and it still does not work.

```
char **tmptr = &p_resistance_str;
```

gives me

```
cannot convert ‘char (*)[94]’ to ‘char**’ in initialization
```

The reason I do this is that if the return value is a string, it will return me a null pointer unless I dynamically allocate the string, return the string, then destroy the string.

Else is it possible to declare a parameter as:

```
char *[] str
```

since I should only be using fixed width strings.

Comment: 1. C != C++ 2. Why is it declared `char **str`? Is it modifying the pointer? Or is it expecting an array of strings? 3. use std::strings

Comment: `char p_resistance_str [...]` You misspelled `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to pass the address of the string if you want to change its elements in the function. It is enough to declare the parameter like

```
char *str
```

and use corresponding argument like

```
p_resistance_str
```

As for the error then your string is defined like

```
char p_resistance_str [ EnhancedSQLobject_STRFIELD_LEN ];
```

So the pointer to the string will have type

```
char ( * ) [ EnhancedSQLobject_STRFIELD_LEN ];
```

Of course it is not the same as `char **`.

Comment: Thanks, it should be easier this way. I compile successfully, but I have to create test code to see if it works. So it will take a while.

Comment: @larienna It seems all you need is to print out the modified string that to be sure that the program is correct.

Comment: I tested it and it works. I made test code because it was very deep in a chain a function call. Since it's a game, it is dependent on some random factor and the information is not displayed on the screen. So I just made a test loop that passes through the table and display the information, then reinsert some of the info into the database and it works in both direction like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
&p_resistance_str
```

is of type char (*)[size] which cannot be converted to char** implicitly.

What you can do is:-

```
char *ptr = p_resistance_str ;
func(&ptr);

void func(char** ptr)  //just used for explanation...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you hate pointers... C/C++ is not for you partner! ;)))

If you want to change the content of this string, you don't need pass a reference of a pointer (char **).

Declare your function as:

```
public: static void bitfield_to_strfield ( s_EnhancedSQLobject_strfield hash[], char *str, int bitfield );
```

And call it as:

```
EnhancedSQLobject::bitfield_to_strfield ( STRFLD_ELEMENTAL_PROPERTY, p_resistance_str, p_resistance );
```

I hope you'll find it useful... but please, give a chance to STD library.

Comment: I know how pointer works, I just try to avoid them. They are a potential source of invisible bugs that blow up 2 months later with no clue to find where is the bug.

Comment: As for the STD class, well I am using allegro which is Cstring Friendly. Also STD class would inflate my program too much and it is not optimized for video games. So I rather finish it they way I start it many years ago. I'll use them in Java instead.

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about what would happen if the compiler allowed you to make this conversion. If you take the address of `p_resistance_str` and then you pass that address into a function, then the function could modify the location of the string to which `p_resistance_str` points. This does not make sense. In fact, you could make `p_resistance_str` point to something of a different size. Specifically, you could point it at something that was not `EnhancedSQLobject_STRFIELD_LEN` long. So this conversion would be entirely unsafe, and that is why it is disallowed. If `bitfield_to_strfield` needs to modify the characters of `p_resistance_str`, then you don't need to pass the address of `p_resistance_str`. If `bitfield_to_strfield` needs to modify **where** its argument points, then you can't pass the address of `p_resistance_str`. Instead you should create a temporary pointer variable and pass it's address instead. If you want that temporary pointer variable to initially have the same contents as `p_resistance_str`, then you can do that as well:

```
char *temp = p_resistance_str;
bitfield_to_strfield(&temp);
```

Note that `temp` may no longer point at the same sequence of `char` as `p_resistance_str` does after the invocation of `bitfield_to_strfield`.